# (LyX) Show Changes in Output (Color Change)

Tags: lyx, changes

- I wrote a paper in `lyx`, and have just received comments from the reviewer.
- The journal wants me to mark all the changes in red.
- I selected `Document-> Change Tracking -> Show Changes in Output`.
- It shows *deletions in red* and *additions in blue*. However, the journal wants ***all changes* in red**.
- Is there any easy way to show the additions in red as well?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble and add the following line:

```
\renewcommand{\lyxadded}[3]{{\color{red}#3}}
```

Make sure to double-check everything carefully (i.e., that this command doesn't have any unintended consequences) before submitting.